# How do I get Symfony to specify my charset in all responses?

Tags: php, symfony

All responses from my Symfony 2 application all have this header line:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

So my browser assumes the output charset is ISO-8859-1. I would like the header to say:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8
```

instead. I know I can do this manually for every response like this:

```
$response->setCharset('UTF-8');
```

But that would be incredibly redundant since my application has lots of controls and will only ever output UTF-8. I have searched in vain for a Symfony configuration setting that controls the default charset. I found `framework.charset` but that seems to be unrelated, and is UTF-8 by default anyway.

How do I get Symfony to specify my charset in all responses?

---

### My thoughts

I know this isn't too much of a problem (most of the time) since I can specify the charset explicitly in both HTML and XML. The issue is when I'm service plain text or JSON, or if I'm dumping variables using `var_dump`. In both cases, all non-ASCII symbols are scrambled as my browser ventures an erroneous guess.

My backup solution is to subclass the response class and put `$this->setCharset('UTF-8')` in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Using setCharset() **doesn't set charset in headers**.

If you want to specify utf-8 encoding in headers, you can use following code somewhere before $app->run()

```
$app->after(
    function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        $response->headers->set(
            'Content-Type', 
            $response->headers->get('Content-Type') . '; charset=UTF-8'
        );

        return $response;
    }
);
```

Additionally if you want your json output to be displayed with unescaped utf8 characters, you can use something like this:

```
$app->after(
    function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $response->headers->get('Content-Type') . '; charset=UTF-8');

        if ($response instanceof JsonResponse) {
            $response->setEncodingOptions(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }

        return $response;
    }
);
```

It sets pretty print as well :)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else helps, keep using `$response->setCharset('UTF-8');`, but put it in a kernel response listener. This is a general pattern in Symfony: everytime you do (almost) the same thing in a lot of controllers, it should go to a kernel response listener instead to keep the controller code straight to the point.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 3.1 just override getCharset() in your AppKernel. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/kernel.html

```
// app/AppKernel.php

// ...
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function getCharset()
    {
        return 'ISO-8859-1';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can tell the framework which charset to use in your config.yml:

```
framework:
  charset:         UTF-8
```

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html

Comment: `RuntimeException: The charset setting is deprecated. Just remove it from your configuration file.`

Comment: charset setting was deprecated.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/4716

use AppKernel::getCharset
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/kernel.html#charset